perforce Helix Core (p4) - how to get depot path when committing
I am using perforce Helix Core (p4)(Perforce Helix Core) for software version control, my target is, when committing a code, perforce automatically write the changelist number to a text file, so when next time I get the codes of a workspace for building(in VisualStudio), I can include the changelist number in the text file as the version number of my codes.
I know the first step is to set the p4 trigger, see below picture

and below is the code of the "update_revision.bat"
@echo off
C:\Progra~1\Git\git-bash.exe "C:\Program Files\Perforce\triggers\update_revision.sh" %1

and below is the beginning codes of the "update_revision.sh"
# 获取变更列表号
CHANGELIST=$1
# 设置本地路径
REVISION_PATH="D:/revision.txt"
CHANGE_DETAILS_PATH="D:/changelist_details.txt"
# 确保 Perforce 环境变量正确设置
export P4PORT=server-pc:8765
export P4USER=Nate
export P4CLIENT=Nate_s0125
# 使用 p4 describe 命令获取变更列表的详细信息
#p4 describe -s $CHANGELIST > "$CHANGE_DETAILS_PATH"
p4 describe -s 5189 > "D:/changelist_details.txt"
# 写入变更列表号到本地文件
echo "Changelist: $CHANGELIST" > "$REVISION_PATH"
echo "Files:" >> "$REVISION_PATH"

about the two lines of code :
#p4 describe -s $CHANGELIST > "$CHANGE_DETAILS_PATH"
p4 describe -s 5189 > "D:/changelist_details.txt"

the first line tries to acquire the changelist contents and write to "D:/changelist_details.txt", but I found changelist_details.txt is empty
then I tried the second line, changelist_details.txt was still empty
but if I execute this line of code directly under command line, it works

anyone knows how to make this line of code work in the update_revision.sh ?
thanks.

Change the command to p4 -s describe -s $CHANGELIST > $CHANGE_DETAILS_PATH and I think you'll find that you're getting an error message (most likely an authentication error, since there's no password/ticket in your script).

Zooming out a bit -- do you need a trigger to do this?  When you build, you can run p4 changes -s submitted -m 1 to get the latest submitted changelist.  You can do p4 files @=CHANGE to get the list of files in any given changelist.  All of this information is stored for you in Perforce's db and very easy to query from the client; there's no need to duplicate it in a server-side trigger.

@Samwise
Really appreciate for your reply.
I am not familiar with perforce(actually the above p4 codes were provided by ChatGPT...). Could you explain more about "When you build, you can run p4 changes -s submitted -m 1 to get the latest submitted changelist", we get our codebase from perforce server and build the codes under VisualStudio, do you mean under VisualStudio we can run the p4 command to get the submitted changelist ? Note we need to get the relevant changelist number of that codebase, not the latest changelist number, thanks.

Ah, ChatGPT's involvement explains why this is so unnecessarily complicated.  :D  p4 is a CLI tool used to run operations on the Perforce server, it should be easy to incorporate it into your VSCode build process.  I recommend having a software engineer on your team who's familiar with your builds take a look at it.

@Samwise
thanks, I had asked ChatGPT again(:D) now I know how to incorporate p4 command while building, but my problem is the same, the below codes works in command prompt, but does not work in update_revision.sh, do you know why ?
p4 describe -s 5189 > "D:/changelist_details.txt"

See first comment.
